# Internet Explorer 6/7 displays Operation Abort message but not always

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I am working on an osCommerce website and few of my page displays the "Operation Abort" message. I have gone through the already given solutions in Google and by SO users, but solutions like using "defer" in script tag, placing the script tag in bottom of page, is not working, the page in which this msg is displayed do not contain any node creation which is generally the main cause of this issue....

the dilemma is I am not encountered with this error every-time, some times it displays and sometimes it doesn't..

I am looking for the solution since last two months but instead of getting t resolved my site traffic is reducing..

please help me, what should i do in this case now...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older one, but I figured I'd throw something in.

Are you using any kind of script that targets IE6/7? Like supersleight/any PNG solution? Are you using JavaScript libraries?

If you are using anything like those, make sure you wrap any initialization code in a domready/onload function. This is where I've seen the problem most often be resolved.